# Duplicated jQuery Tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tabs

I have tabs above my tab content.

As long as my tab content is long, I duplicate my tabs also below the tab content.

So, It looks like:

> [tab 1] [tab 2]
>
> --content
>
> [tab 1] [tab 2]

I use css and jQuery.

When I change tab-list above, normally css effects change. but It doesn't change on the bottom tab-list.

And same is also true for bottom; when I change tab on the tab-list bottom, css effects only changes on the bottom but not above tab-list.

**I want to change them at once because it looks confusing like that.**

**HTML:**

```
<div class="tabs">

    <ul class="tab-links">
        <li class="active"><a href="#tab1">Tab #1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab2">Tab #2</a></li>
    </ul>  

    <div class="tab-content">

        <div id="tab1" class="tab active">#1 content</div>

        <div id="tab2" class="tab">#2 content </div> 

    </div>

    <div class="tabs">

        <ul class="tab-links">
            <li class="active"><a href="#tab1">Tab #1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab2">Tab #2</a></li>
        </ul>

    </div>

</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.tabs .tab-links a').on('click', function(e)  {
        var currentAttrValue = jQuery(this).attr('href');

        // Show/Hide Tabs
       jQuery('.tabs ' + currentAttrValue).slideDown(400).siblings().slideUp(400); 

       // Change/remove current tab to active
        jQuery(this).parent('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

       e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

**jsFiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/4m2ut16k/

*

I was expecting it to work like that because CSS codes are the same, so if it works in tab-list-above, why not working in tab-list-bottom?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need use selector and add active to all li that have `a` with the same `href`

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.tabs .tab-links a').on('click', function(e)  {
        var currentAttrValue = jQuery(this).attr('href');

        // Show/Hide Tabs
       jQuery('.tabs ' + currentAttrValue).slideDown(400).siblings().slideUp(400); 

       console.log(currentAttrValue);
        jQuery(".tab-links li").removeClass("active");
        jQuery('a[href="'+currentAttrValue+'"]').parent('li').addClass('active');

       e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4m2ut16k/1/

Comment: Thanks. It worked like a magic. Thank you very much!! I have another question if you like to answer. As long as content is long, user has to scroll-up to page when he change the tab on the tab-list-bottom. Can we make page go up automatically when user change the tab from below?

Comment: add `jQuery(".tab-content").scrollTop(0);` into the code :)

Comment: I tried it everywhere I can, but couldn't make it work. [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4m2ut16k/7/) added but doesn't scrollTop somehow.

Comment: I thought that had a height div if you want scroll page you can use `jQuery(window).scrollTop(0);`

Comment: Yes you were right, there is a `div class` named `tab-content` but it doesn't scroll there, very stange. I can't use `jQuery(window).scrollTop(0);` because tabs are kind of not on the top. So I can't figure out why `jQuery(".tab-content").scrollTop(0);` doesn't work.

Comment: you set height for tab-content?

Comment: `.tab-content {
    height: auto;
}` and `.tab-content {
    height: 1000px;
}` doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the problem is not jquery, but as you point change, if you want to change the two tabs at the same time not point to This, as this refers only to the clicked object, and not the class in general, certainly can pestrañas achieve the effect of using only cSS-3 thanks to the "input: checked and label"

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your code on fiddle. I hope this will work.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.tabs .tab-links a').on('click', function(e)  {
        var currentAttrValue = jQuery(this).attr('href');

        // Show/Hide Tabs
       jQuery('.tabs ' + currentAttrValue).slideDown(400).siblings().slideUp(400); 

       // Change/remove current tab to active
  var indexTab    =  jQuery( "li" ).index(jQuery(this).parent('li'));
  jQuery('ul.tab-links').each(function(){jQuery(this).find('li').eq(indexTab).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');});

       e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4m2ut16k/5/)